# Remove Elements after Some certain Element

Tags: jquery

I have a list of item

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class="remove">
            <li>1</li>
        </ul> <--Remove
        <ul>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul> <--Remove
        <ul>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul> // .remove ul ends here 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to delete all the closing  tag that I have shown arrow after the class `.remove` ??

Comment: You mean you want to remove closing tags only?

Comment: I have tried this one. But it removes all ul. 
 $('.remove').nextAll('ul').remove();

Comment: @dotnetom Yes i wan to remove closing tag that i have shown arrow in the question..

Comment: if you want to remove closing tags only (which is invalid html!!!) then you need to do this with parsing the `.html()` yourself, remove them and put the html back in. But that would be in vain, since the browser would autocorrect your wrong html and remove the start tags as well. Maybe you want to rethink on that...

Comment: @TehSphinX Hmmm, I agree with all what you said (which is what I've already explained in my answer below) except the last sentence. Which browser did you use that removed the opening tags? I tested it in IE and it added the closing tags, and I think other browsers should do the same, shouldn't they?

Comment: To be honest: I assumed that and did not consider it could add them. Mainly I wanted to make the point that it doesn't help to remove closing tags without the opening tags, which is still valid. Glad you tested it, though :]

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works on valid DOM, so you cannot just remove the closing tags. With the help of JavaScript, you can remove the closing tags, but only in a string variable:

```js
var ul = $('ul.remove').siblings('ul');
var removed = "";
for (var i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
  removed += ul[i].outerHTML.substring(0, ul[i].outerHTML.length - 5);
}


alert(removed);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="remove">
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't know of a good way to place it back into the DOM because once you do that, the browser will make valid HTML by adding those closing tags back. The only **bad** way I can think of is to save the string variable directly into a file (along with the rest of the HTML), but obviously that cannot be done from a website and likely not what you want.

But why do you want to remove the closing tags anyway? If you wanted to actually merge the `ul`s into the first one with the class "remove", then you can follow Parvan's answer, but I find the code below easier to understand and possible a bit faster:

```js
var remove = $('ul.remove');
var siblings = remove.siblings('ul');
remove.append(siblings.children());
siblings.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="remove">
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```